# $a_n=(n-1)a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, recurrence-relations, closed-form, hypergeometric-function

In an answer to a recent question of mine, I was introduced to the recurrence relation $$a_n=(n-1)a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$$
Where $a_1=0,a_2=1$. I have computational [evidence that $a_n=a_{-n}$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sd2j8oc31b), as I have computed up to $a_{10}=516901$, and $a_{-10}=516901$. But, so far I don't really see a pattern in the numbers which could help me with my closed form. Of course, there's the patterns one gets by using the general case,
$$a_n=(n-1)\bigg[(n-2)a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}\bigg]+a_{n-2}$$ 
$$a_n=(n-1)\bigg[(n-2)\bigg[(n-3)a_{n-3}+a_{n-4}\bigg]+a_{n-3}\bigg]+a_{n-2}$$
And so on. These patterns suggest some sort of series of factorials of various types, yet I do not think that going on and on like that would be very productive. As you can see, I am pretty lost.

I heard that one could express this sort of recurrence relation with hypergeometric functions. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

**Update:**

The [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A001053) proposes that the relation has the formula 
$$a_n=2K_1(2)I_n(-2)+2I_1(2)K_n(2)$$
Where 
$$I_\alpha(x)=\sum_{m\geq0}\frac1{m!\Gamma(m+\alpha+1)}\bigg(\frac x2\bigg)^{2m+\alpha}$$ 
Is the modified Bessel Function of the second kind.

And 
$$K_\alpha(x)=\frac\pi2\frac{I_{-\alpha}(x)-I_\alpha(x)}{\sin\pi\alpha}$$
Is the modified bessel function of the second kind.

How does one derive this formula?

Comment: Your sequence appears as [A001053](https://oeis.org/A001053) in the OEIS. It has some results for the closed form, specifically in terms of Bessel functions and in terms of hypergeometric functions.

Comment: @Semiclassical Thanks. The currently posted answer provides the same link. I'll edit the questions to include the closed forms, but I still want to learn how to derive them.

Comment: You can prove $a_n = a_{-n}$ by induction on $n$ straightforwardly (since the recursion yields $a_{-n+2} = \left(-n+1\right) a_{-n+1} + a_{-n}$, which rewrites as $a_{-n} = \left(n-1\right) a_{-n+1} + a_{-n+2}$). The same holds for any recursion of the form $a_n = F\left(n-1\right) a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$, where $F$ is any odd function from $\mathbb{Z}$ to an additive abelian group, provided that it holds for $n = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modified [Bessel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Recurrence_relations) functions of the first kind have the recurrence relation

$$
\frac{2\alpha}{x}C_{\alpha}(x) = C_{\alpha - 1}(x) - C_{\alpha + 1}(x) \tag{1}
$$

where $C_\alpha$ denotes $I_\alpha$, $e^{\alpha i \pi} K_\alpha$. Take $\alpha = n-1$ and $x = 2$

$$
C_{n} (2) = -(n - 1)C_{n-1}(2) + C_{n-2}(2) \tag{2}
$$

And you can see from here that this looks already looks a lot like your problem. For example, if you take $I_n$, then you have

$$
I_n(2) = -(n - 1)I_{n-1}(2) + I_{n-2}(2) \tag{3}
$$

The problem is the sign in the first term, but that one is easy to figure out, because the $I_n$ has the parity of $n$. So if $n$ is even, $n$ is odd and you can move the minus to the argument. If $n$ is odd, $n-1$ is even, and you can multiply by $-1$ everything and move the sign to the argument again. You can repeat the same analysis for $K$ and reach the conclusion that

$$
a_n = c_1 I_n(-2) + c_2 K_n(2) \tag{4}
$$

The constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ you can find with the seeds $a_1 = 0$, $a_2 = 1$

Comment: Perfect! thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Hint to show $a_n=a_{-n}$: Let $b_n=a_{-n}$, and see that $b_0=1$, $b_1=0$, $b_2=2$. Now

$$a_n=(n-1)a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$$

Substituting $n=-k+2$,

$$a_{-k+2}=(-k+1)a_{-k+1}+a_{-k}$$

$$b_{k-2}=(-k+1)b_{k-1}+b_k$$

$$b_k=(k-1)b_{k-1}+b_{k-2}.$$

So, $b_n$ has the same first recurrence relation as $a_n$ and it also has the same first two terms, so we can show (by induction) that $b_n=a_n$ for all $n$.

Finding a closed form is likely to be difficult: for example, the [OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/A001053) has no such form.

Comment: Thanks for the proof. It makes sense. (+1)